# Is there a way to pass a JSON object/Server data, to the main JS module generated from webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, module, bundle

HI everyone hope you are going well!

First of all I am a backend developer, not a frontend, but I do lots of front-end code as well however I never used Webpack in the past and I ended looking for webpack because of my requirements that are pretty much the follows:

1. Instead of use old JS way, I am using modules to decouple program logic into components
2. I need to bundle and minify those js into one bundlefile.
3. I need to pass server data to those functions inside the modules like JSON objects coming from the server.

For start I have the following configuration files for:

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "testWebpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
   "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
   },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.13.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
}
```

and the JS is pretty basic such for this example:

src\person.js

```
export default class Person
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.Name = "Your name";
    }
}
```

and src\main.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import p from './person';

export default function myTempFunction(allData) 
{  
    // Lodash, currently included via a script, is required for this line to work
    const value = _.join([allData.welcome, new p().Name], ' ');
  
    console.log(value);
}

// myTempFunction({
//   welcome: "Hello"
// });
```

dist\index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Getting Started</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="module">
      import myTempFunction from './main.js';      
      myTempFunction({
        welcome: "Hello from the server"
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when running I get an

```
The requested module './main.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

My idea is that in the server (I am using asp.net core) I am producing a JSON which I wanna pass to this modules and I need to pass the object inside the main function.

*As you can see I have commented the myTempFunction inside src\main.js. If I uncomment that works but at that stage I don't have my serverData to pass.*

I really searched on the web but I can't find any solution for this, maybe I am going something wrong in my thinking and I am feeling a bit odd.

At the same time It may feel right to do what I do inside the `<script type="module">` but Make no sense because I want to get that function from webpack instead of loading the module using the Browser engine.

Any idea from the frontend devs where can give me an hint? I would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: For the index.html file you should look into https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/ which will create index.html and also inject the created bundle js file. You should also look into https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/ and maybe use `@babel/preset-env` which will transpile your javascript source code to js code compatible for the most browsers. As for the server data what you usually do is create api endpoint on the server and then use something like axios or fetch to make http request from the client to the server.

Comment: actually, I am populating Vue instances with the serverData thats why I need to pass it to the bundled file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue but in what way do you plan to pass the data?

Comment: I am passing data from the server to Vue as a JSON object to get that data and load the classes with that data. Vue wil then pick the viewModel and render the component. Thats why I am passing the server data to the client, to pretty much load client JS models and Vue render the dependent components

Comment: That sounds like a different issue then the one shown in the code you posted here.

Comment: its unrelatted with vue. All I need is to pass data to the function imported from the bundler. Then the code in main should receive that data and call vue, etc... and other stuff that depends on that data..